# Do procedures need separate access Rights on Tables?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, privileges

I have access on tables but when I run the same query in Anonymous block it fails with

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: **when I run the same query in Anonymous block** then What??

Answer (score 6):

The Oracle security model means that we cannot build database objects (views, stored procedures, etc) using privileges granted to our account through a role.  The privileges have to be explicitly granted to our named account.

This applies to anonymous blocks as well.

So, if you want to build PL/SQL which runs against database objects in other schemas you will have to ask the schema owner - or the DBA - to grant you the privileges you need.